# Why do variadic templates behave like this in c++?

Tags: c++, class, templates, recursion, variadic-templates

I need help understanding this piece of code. There are no loops available, so how can the template, which I know is processed at compilation time, fetch all the arguments, and why did it call the same variable "`c`" which was incremented even though it is only in the specialized "`Z`" version ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

class Z
{
    Z() {}
    virtual ~Z() {}
};

class A
{
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B
{
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {}
};

template <class P, class... args>
class TCount : public TCount<args...>
{
public:
    TCount() : TCount<args...>() { this->c++; }
    virtual ~TCount() {}
};

template <>
class TCount<Z>
{
protected:
    int c;

public:
    TCount() { c = 0; }
    int getC() { return c; }
    virtual ~TCount() {}
};

int main()
{
    TCount<A, B, A, B, Z> tCount;
    cout << tCount.getC() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you said "template, which I know is processed at compilation time" the template it self is processed at compilation time not the the data members!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is in the recursion of the class definition.

I mean... when you define

```
TCount <A,B,A,B,Z> tCount;
```

you have that

- `TCount<A,B,A,B,Z>` inherits from `TCount<B,A,B,Z>`
- `TCount<B,A,B,Z>` inherits from `TCount<A,B,Z>`
- `TCount<A,B,Z>` inherits from `TCount<B,Z>`
- `TCount<B,Z>` inherits from `TCount<Z>`
- `TCount<Z>` define `c` and initialize it to zero
- `TCount<B,Z>` inherit `c` and, in body constructor, increment it (`c` become `1`)
- `TCount<A,B,Z>` inherit `c` and, in body constructor, increment it (`c` become `2`)
- `TCount<B,A,B,Z>` inherit `c` and, in body constructor, increment it (`c` become `3`)
- `TCount<A,B,A,B,Z>` inherit `c` and, in body constructor, increment it (`c` become `4`)

Comment: I would say that not the `TCount` defines `c`, but the `TCount<Z>`. This code wouldn't work if we use other class at the end of this variadic template, i.e. `TCount< Z, A>`

Comment: I didn't get your point @DmitryKuzminov, why wouldn't it work ?

Comment: @MinaAshraf - Try defining, by example, `TCount<A, B, A, B>`; you get a compilation error because `TCount<A, B>` inherit from `TCount<B>` but `TCount<B>` doesn't matches the `TCount<Z>` specialization so matches the general case, so inherit from `TCount<>` (empty variadic list) but `TCount` is defined with one or more template argument; compilation error!

Comment: You need to stop the recursion somehow. So far you have a definition of the template class that takes one or more classes as template arguments, but you have no definition of the class that takes no arguments at all. You also have a specialization for the template class for the argument Z which allows you to stop the recursion for the case of instantiation of TCount<[list of classes], Z>